# How do you rotate an object in OpenGL a certain number of degrees? Is there a built-in command or do I have to use a formula?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, graphics, formula

How do you rotate an object in OpenGL a certain number of degrees? Is there a built-in command or do I have to use a formula? I've been stuck on this issue for days. Its a program that draws a shape under my mouse as it moves.

Say I have a drawing function:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glColor3f ( 1, 1, 1 );
glBegin (toggle_type );

//Where cur_x and cur_y is the current mouse location that gets auto-updated
//ratiox is 0.7 and ratioy is 0.6
if (toggle_type==GL_QUADS) //rectangle from (-length, -length) to (length,length) 
{
    glVertex2f ( cur_x- length*ratiox, cur_y + length*ratioy );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x+ length*ratiox, cur_y + length*ratioy );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x+ length*ratiox, cur_y- length*ratioy );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x-  length*ratiox, cur_y- length*ratioy );
}
else if (toggle_type==GL_TRIANGLES)//triangle with vertices (-length, -length), (length, -length), (0, length).
{
    glVertex2f ( cur_x- length, cur_y - length );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x+length, cur_y - length );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x, cur_y + length );
}

else if (toggle_type==GL_LINES) //line brush with vertices (0,-length), (0,length)
{

    glVertex2f ( cur_x, cur_y - length );
    glVertex2f ( cur_x, cur_y + length );
}
```

I can't just use glRotatef() before I use glBegin can I? I want to rotate the way it's drawn around my mouse a certain number of degrees. Is there not a built in function? What formula should I look into using if not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn how to use OpenGL transforms: glTranslate, glRotate, and glScale.

Translate means "move stuff."  Scale means "make stuff bigger or smaller."  Rotate means what it sounds like it means.

With OpenGL transforms, it helps to think in terms of changing the coordinate system every time you issue a transform.

So to do this, let's saying you're drawing a box around the cursor.  First translate to the position of the mouse cursor.  That's where you want to do your drawing.  Then rotate the coordinate system around the cursor, so you can draw a box easily without having to do funny stuff with sines and cosines and angles.  Then, scale the object to whatever size you want it to be -- this shrinks or expands the coordinate system.  Finally, just draw a one-unit-across box around the origin (0,0), and it will appear on screen in the location, rotation, and size you want.

If you try to rotate before you translate, you'll get incorrect results.  The technical reason for this is that OpenGL post-multiplies transform matrices by vertex vectors.

And, yes, you should do all transforms outside of your begin/end block.  Your begin/end block is just for specifying vertices, normals, etc.

Comment: The matrix stack has been removed from OpenGL-3. Instead you're expected to build the matrices yourself and supply shader code to transform the vertex data with them. Also the immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd) has been depreciated and removed.

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing with freeglut to see if multi windows can work (seem it does!), and i was using rotations to see some change in display:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#define DEGREES_X_SEC 10.0
int w_dc, w_ds;
float yRotationAngle;

void DrawSphere()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glRotatef(yRotationAngle, .3f, .3f, .3f);
    glutWireSphere(.3, 20, 20);
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void DrawCube()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glRotatef(yRotationAngle, .2f, .2f, .2f);
    glutWireCube(.5);
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void Idle()
{
    static int previousTime = 0;
    int currentTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (currentTime - previousTime > 10)
    {
        float x_frame = (DEGREES_X_SEC / 1000.0) * (currentTime - previousTime);
        yRotationAngle += x_frame;
        glutPostWindowRedisplay(w_dc);
        glutPostWindowRedisplay(w_ds);
        previousTime = currentTime;
    }
}

// other code here....

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // let glut eat any command line args that it owns
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    // full color, double buffered
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);

    w_dc = make_window("cube", DrawCube);
    glutPositionWindow(100, 100);

    w_ds = make_window("sphere", DrawSphere);
    glutPositionWindow(200, 200);

    // not bound to any window
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

HTH, of course requires freeglut...

Answer (score -3):

you need to focus an allegraic material like c 5 and m2, this is automatic rotation and will be instantly rewarded by the government because it shows abnormal behaviour, let me know if this helps.

Rog.